# How to pass a string array from Search textbox in asp.net WebSite to 'Search.aspx' page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working on an asp.net C# website and have just started implementing the search. I have a search.aspx page that uses full-text search with the code below:

```
    protected List<string> keywords = new List<string>();

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Turn user input to a list of keywords.
        string[] keywords = tbKeyWords.Text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // The basic validation.
        if (keywords.Length <= 0)
        {
            lbAlert.Text = "Please input keyword.";
            return;
        }
        this.keywords = keywords.ToList();

        // Do search operation with DataAccess.cs page.
        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
        List<Article> list = dataAccess.Search(this.keywords);

        ShowResult(list);
    }
```

This code and page works. However, I can't figure out how to get this page to work with the search textbox I have at the top of my site in the MasterPage.

How can I make it so that when a user types something in the search box and hits the search button, it redirects them to the search.aspx page while simultaneously running the above method? I assume I should be using some sort of query string, but my efforts have been fruitless thus far.

Comment: Is the search textbox in a different form than the form with `runat="server"` on it?

Comment: No, that is the Form it is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the search box redirect to the search page with the arguments in the querystring. Then have your search page either use the querystring or use the button click, depending on what happened. Your `search.aspx` could have code like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["searchTerm"]))
    {
        string[] keywords = Request.QueryString["searchTerm"].ToString().Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        RunSearch(keywords);
    }
}

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] keywords = tbKeyWords.Text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    RunSearch(keywords);
}

private void RunSearch(string[] keywords)
{
    if (keywords.Length <= 0)
    {
        lbAlert.Text = "Please input keyword.";
        return;
    }
    this.keywords = keywords.ToList();

    // Do search operation with DataAccess.cs page.
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
    List<Article> list = dataAccess.Search(this.keywords);

    ShowResult(list);
}
```

The searchbox in your masterpage could have a button with a click event that would fire a javascript function, like:

```
function searchSite() {
    window.location = "/search.aspx?searchTerm=" + document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
}
```

**Unsolicited Opinion**

You stated this is in the main form for the site (the one with `runat="server"`). My personal recommendation is to move your search box OUTSIDE of that form, like:

```
<form action="javascript:searchSite()">
    <input type="text" id="searchInput"  />
</form>
```

Why? If they are on your login page, and type in your search box and click "enter" (typical user behavior), is the search going to fire? Or is the default "submit" button going to fire and try to log them in, likely giving them an error? In my opinion, this is the simplest way to avoid confusion.

Comment: It depends on how you are submitting the form. Is it actually redirecting in javascript? Or is it executing some code-behind you have that redirects?

Comment: Yes but if that is an `asp:Textbox` the IDs might not matchup. You may need to post your code.

Comment: If it is a server control, you'd need to use `document.getElementById('<%= searchInput.ClientID %>')`.

Comment: Does the case match in the JavaScript function? My initial post had it all lower case. Also that form must be outside of your other main form.

Comment: Thanks Mike!!! I purposely put it right before the closing </form> tag, stupid me. 0.o  Just a quick question, this puts the textbox in the bottom left corner since its not part of my other form. Can I use CSS to position it up towards the top where searchbox's are suppose to be?

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in `Session` from your search box control/master page/whatever, then load it from session on `Page_Load` of the search page (I would recommend removing it from `Session` after that)